# Type name does not allow storage class to be specified？

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here is code in `log.h` file :

```
struct SUCC_CODE{
   static const int  RECOGNIZER_OK = 0;
};
```

The above piece of code in `log.h` file throwing compiler error:

```
Type name does not allow storage class to be specified
```

Comment: Possible duplicate Question[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013373/usage-of-static-within-a-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Struct members may not be `static`. Remove that specifier, and the compiler should stop complaining. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6013373/1292061) explains that it is a valid specifier in C++.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn’t allow you to use `static` within a struct. It’s not even clear what that would mean in a C struct.