# How to create a 'static' variable for a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, static

I would like to have a struct that functions like this:

struct

- member 1 (every instance of the struct has its own value of this)
- static member (every struct shares this member)

I am aware that the static keyword does not do this. 
My question is, how can I mimic this behavior?

Could I create a member that is pointer to a global variable?

Is there some other better way to do this?

Comment: If the member is common to all `structs` why include it as a member?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, it is not object oriented. You cannot do `struct::static_member` in C.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013373/c-usage-of-static-within-a-struct

Answer (score 3):

Unlike structs in C++ which can have static data members, C structs don't have such a construct.

Since this is a common value for anyone that may use it, just declare it as a global:

```
int my_struct_common_val = 42;

struct my_struct {
    ...
};
```

Comment: If this is in a header file then you will need to use `extern int my_struct_common_val;` with definition in exactly one `.c` file